The odd case of two blood avengers targeting each other
Here’s the case: Shimon kills Levi’s brother accidentally, and Levi kills Shimons brother accidentally close to the same time
Both Shimon and Levi are obligated to go to the city of refuge
Both Shimon and Levi also have a right to kill each other (or according to R. Yose Makkot 11a, a mitzvah to do so)
I am wondering, what are they obligated to do? Specifically according to R. Yose who says it’s a mitzvah to kill would this push off the mitzvah of running to the city of refuge. Or must they both run to the city of refuge and only try killing on the way but they can’t stop to do so?

Does pikuach nefesh not push off the mitzvah of avenging your brother's blood, just like it pushes off everything except the Big 3?

It does, but in this case either running to the city of refuge or avenging the blood would save you from pikuach nefesh…so which takes precedence?

I didn't fuly see the chiddush here until now. Very nice question! Still, arriving im the ir haMiklat is certain safety, but a given person may or may not survive a fight

Can the authorities arrest them and send them to two different cities of refuge?

@יהושעק Given that a manslaughter culprit is likely to defend himself against the גואל הדם (and would not be punished for doing so), perhaps it is not so clear that pikuach nefesh pushes off this. (Going to war would be another example of something that overrides pikuach nefesh).
